# How to use tuneup.js waitUntilFoundByName?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to understand how to use [tuneup.js](http://www.tuneupjs.org/extensions.html) but I can't get the wait helpers to work at all, for example:

```
mainWindow.waitUntilFoundByName("loadingLabel", 15);
```

If I do a `target.logElementTree();` I can see the `UILabel` named `loadingLabel`. What's the correct way of using these?

Answer (score 0):

according to [Assertions](http://www.tuneupjs.org/assertions.html) and [Extensions](http://www.tuneupjs.org/extensions.html) of tuneup.js:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
window.elements()[XX].prototype.waitUntilVisible(15);
var namelabel = window.element()[XX].name();
assertEquals('loadingLabel',namelabel);
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`waitUntilFoundByName` only looks at the direct children of an element.  Unless the element you're looking for would be found at `mainWindow.labels()["loadingLabel"]`, this won't be able to find it.

If you want to be able to do a more "fuzzy" search of the element tree, you'll need to check out [mechanic.js](http://www.cozykozy.com/mechanicjs/) or the tuneup-esque Illuminator framework (which I wrote), which does this through [selectors](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/docs/Selectors.md).